# Custom SimpleCursorAdapter doesn't bind data, and shows rows even when there's no data

Tags: android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

So I'm trying to make a custom SimpleCursorAdapter, because I want to make list rows that look something like this:
ToggleButton | TextView | ImageButton,
and I know of no way to do this without making a custom adapter.

The problem being that my code doesn't work and I'm not really sure why. Even if there's no data to be displayed, I get a row with the default format:
ToggleButton | "default" | ImageButton.

Furthermore, all rows displayed look exactly the same as the default row, and the OnClickListener I set up doesn't do anything.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, or at least point me in the direction of a decent tutorial for how to deal with custom CursorAdapters and OnClickListeners? Because I've been totally unable to find anything remotely helpful.

Here is my code for the adapter:

```
public class AlarmCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

private Cursor mCursor;
private Context mContext;
private Activity mActivity;

public AlarmCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
        String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    mCursor = c;
    mContext = context;
    mActivity = (Activity) context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if(view == null) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.alarm_list_row, parent, false);
    }
    if(mCursor == null || mCursor.getCount() == 0) {
        return view;
    }
    mCursor.moveToPosition(position);

    // Set the alarm time view
    TextView alarmView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.alarmView);
    int timeStringIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DailyAlarmTable.ALARM_TIME);
    String alarmTime = mCursor.getString(timeStringIndex);
    alarmView.setText(alarmTime);

    // Set up the toggle button
    int isActiveIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DailyAlarmTable.ALARM_ISACTIVE);
    int isActive = mCursor.getInt(isActiveIndex);
    ToggleButton alarmToggle = (ToggleButton)view.findViewById(R.id.alarmToggle);
    if(isActive == 1) {
        alarmToggle.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        alarmToggle.setChecked(false);
    }
    final int currentPosition = mCursor.getPosition();
    int idIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DailyAlarmTable.ALARM_ID);
    final long alarmId = mCursor.getLong(idIndex);
    alarmToggle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String toastStr = "clicked alarm " + alarmId + " at position " + currentPosition;
            Toast.makeText(mContext, toastStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });

    return view;
}

}
```

Here's the implementation, which occurs inside a fragment:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    /*
    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.alarm_list_row, null,
            new String[] { DailyAlarmTable.ALARM_TIME, DailyAlarmTable.ALARM_ISACTIVE },
            new int[] { R.id.alarmView, R.id.alarmToggle }, 0);

    */
    mAdapter = new AlarmCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.alarm_list_row, null,
            new String[] { DailyAlarmTable.ALARM_TIME, DailyAlarmTable.ALARM_ISACTIVE },
            new int[] { R.id.alarmView, R.id.alarmToggle }, 0);

    //mAdapter.setViewBinder(new AlarmViewBinder());
    ListView alarmList = (ListView) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.alarmListView);
    TextView emptyView = (TextView) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.empty);
    alarmList.setEmptyView(emptyView);
    alarmList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    // Initialize the loader
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, savedInstanceState, this);
}
```

Here's the XML file for the row:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/alarmToggle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true"
    android:text="@string/details_default" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/alarmView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/details_default"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/alarmDiscard"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_discard"
    android:contentDescription="@string/alarm_discard_description" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If there's any other code you need, I can gladly add that. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I am quite sure you dont have to extend SCA, all you need to do is to implement this iface http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder.html

Comment: I tried using a view binder, but I wasn't sure how I could implement a button that allows me to delete a row. Is it possible to implement such a button in a view binder?

Comment: Add the id of the button to "to" array and some fake column to "from" array and setup the listener there

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that and let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by pskink's comment, the solution was not to use a custom SCA at all, but to just implement a View Binder.